# Android multi-touch headaches

Tags: android, touchscreen

I've getting a real problem trying to deal with multi-touch events. Basically I need to detect if someone has released a finger while touching the screen elsewhere.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268426/android-difference-between-action-up-and-action-pointer-up) previously answered question, I should be using MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP MotionEvent.ACTION_UP.

As far as I can tell, the following code should tell me if a finger has been lifted:

```
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    mCurUp = ( action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) || ( action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP );
```

What I am seeing in practice, is that this works *some* of the time. If I am really careful I can hold my left finger on the screen and lift my right finger and no events are fired at all! Usually at some point my left finger will wobble, generating a *ACTION_MOVE* event. At this point it generates an event (262) which I think correlates to *ACTION_POINTER_UP*

So I'm wondering if any other folks have seen this, and I also suspect it might be the notoriously poor touchscreen on my HTC Desire causing this. Or perhaps I am doing something fundamentally wrong. Does anyone have some tested code that can *reliably* detect lifting either finger from the touchscreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible that the weird behaviour is caused by your device (HTC Desire == Nexus One screen), rather than your code.

Do you know although Android support multi-touch, not every phone support real multitouch?

Have a read of this

http://androidandme.com/2010/03/news/is-multitouch-broken-on-the-nexus-one/

and this

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/70e9dd235d519955

Cheers

Comment: Yes I'm aware the touchscreen isn't very good (at least regarding mult-touch).

Answer (score 0):

This class looks like it has a workaround for your problem and many others caused by buggy multitouch implementation on some android 1.x/2.x devices

http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/

The issue you mentioned is explained there as follows:

> NOTE: rotation is quirky on older touchscreen devices that use a Synaptics or 
>       Synaptics-like "2x1D" sensor (G1, MyTouch, Droid, Nexus One) and not a true 2D
>       sensor like the HTC Incredible or HTC EVO 4G. The quirky behavior results from
>       "axis snapping" when the two points get close together in X or Y, and "ordinate 
>       confusion" where (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) get confused for (x1,y2) and (x2,y1). 
>       There is no way around this other than to keep the two fingers in the same two 
>       relative quadrants (i.e. keep them on a leading or a trailing diagonal), or to 
>       disallow rotation on these devices. 
>       (In spite of misinformation on the Web, there is also no firmware or software 
>       update that can fix this problem, it is a hardware limitation. Hopefully all 
>       newer phones will have a true 2D touch sensor.)