# Make OnTouchListener update all the time

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have an Android applciation which I want it to draw circles around

I used OnTouchListener.

The problem is, when the users "holds" the circle in place, it doesn't update the action.

How can I know if the user's finger is on,when he doesn't move it, with the OnTouchListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to check if what kind of event is triggering onTouchEvent.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //Do Nothing
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //Do Something
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //Do Nothing
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }

        // Schedules a repaint.
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```

More Information about MotionEvents can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html).

Comment: Only just MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, do not use ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP

Answer (score 1):

You can know that by using

```
MotionEvents:
```

Reed more here: [MotionEvents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)

```
ACTION_DOWN is for the first finger that touches the screen. This starts the gesture. The pointer data for this finger is always at index 0 in the MotionEvent.
ACTION_POINTER_DOWN is for extra fingers that enter the screen beyond the first. The pointer data for this finger is at the index returned by getActionIndex().
ACTION_POINTER_UP is sent when a finger leaves the screen but at least one finger is still touching it. The last data sample about the finger that went up is at the index returned by getActionIndex().
ACTION_UP is sent when the last finger leaves the screen. The last data sample about the finger that went up is at index 0. This ends the gesture.
ACTION_CANCEL means the entire gesture was aborted for some reason. This ends the gesture.
```

here is a good answer to read [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4269592/1932105)

Comment: I think that is ACTION_MOVE

Answer (score 0):

Filter touches by what kind they are:

```
boolean onScreen = false;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float eventX = event.getX(); //X coord of the touch
    float eventY = event.getY(); //Y coord of the touch

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // User has touched the screen
        onScreen = true;
        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        // Finger is being dragged on the screen
        onScreen = true; //Not required, just for clarity purposes.
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // User has lifter finger
        onScreen = false;
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }

    if(onScreen) {
        //Finger is on the screen
    }
    return true;
}
```